# Redux Form FieldArrays autofill

Tags: redux-form, react-redux-form

I'm using a field array which consists of email fields. It looks like this:

```
{fields.map((member, index) => (
            <li key={index}>
                <div className="form-group d-flex align-items-start">
                    <Field
                        name={`${member}.email`}
                        type="email"
                        component={renderField}
                        placeholder="Email"
                    />
                </div>
            </li>
        ))}
```

On Chrome, when you autofill one field with a stored email, it autofills the rest with the same email.

For the time being, I've turned off autocomplete, but this is not working. I would like a better way to do this, so that users can autofill a given field, but the rest of them are not autofilled.